# magento2 phtml if else echo not show

Tags: magento2.3

In my file php:

```
$quoteId  = $_item->getId();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerObj = $objectManager->create('Mageplaza\CustomProductDesigner\Api\CustomerDataRepositoryInterface');
$customerData = $customerObj->getByQuoteItemId($quoteId);
$customerDataImage = json_decode($customerData->getCustomerData());
$previews = [];
if(is_object($customerDataImage) || is_array($customerDataImage)){
    foreach ($customerDataImage as $data) {
        if (is_object($data)) {
            $previews[] = $data->preview;
        }
    }
}
$imageDesign = '';
if(count($previews) > 0){
    $imageDesign = $previews[0];
}
```

In my file phtml when i write 2 line echo

```
<?php echo '<img src="'.$imageDesign.'" />'; ?>
<?php echo $block->getImage($block->getProductForThumbnail(), 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->toHtml(); ?>
```

[image]
When i write 2 line it working but when i set check if else it not working

```
<?php if($imageDesign): ?>
    <?php echo '<img src="'.$imageDesign.'" />'; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $block->getImage($block->getProductForThumbnail(), 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[image]
Please help me!

Comment: which error it show to you?

Comment: no it don't have error. But i mage not show

Comment: i have edited the question

Comment: What does `$imageDesign` contain ? `$imageDesign = ?`

Comment: $imageDesign is url image the first. If product have url image first will have else will have show url image second

Comment: @HưngNguyễn can you please share the content, example `$imageDesign = $_product->getProductUrl()...`

Comment: yes i have update. plese check it help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code :

```
<?php if($imageDesign != ''): ?>
    <?php echo '<img src="'.$imageDesign.'" />'; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $block->getImage($block->getProductForThumbnail(), 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Or you can use like this :

```
  <?php if(!empty($imageDesign)): ?>
        <?php echo '<img src="'.$imageDesign.'" />'; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $block->getImage($block->getProductForThumbnail(), 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->toHtml(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I have check but it not show...

Comment: This is link image: https://serving.photos.photobox.com/067360967f280e6c2f707ab75fa3db358945e1d04a76312a5079730e6b91f1d364b52775.jpg

Comment: Answer updated, please check and let me know.

Comment: thank you you @DhirenVasoya